# Play a video at first boot

Tags: boot

i have created my own distro. I want to play a welcome video  after the installation completes and the computer restarts. can i do that in remastersys by editing the configuration files.

i have no experience in coding.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but *your distro* is off-topic here.

Comment: I think in the context of using Ubuntu and Remastersys to customise Ubuntu, we could consider this on-topic. We've talked about the line between customising and a distinct distribution before on Meta and I don't think adding a start-up video really constitutes as a major enough change.

Comment: @Jobin I don't think merely changing the splash logo and name makes my distro off-topic. it's still ubuntu